# How do I synchronize AST elements and cursor position?

Tags: parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I am using a parser to retrieve the AST of some code typed in an editor. What I would like to achieve now is this: Given the cursor position in the editor (row, column), find the currently selected AST element. However, I have no idea how this can be done, are there any standard ways to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you stamp each AST node with source file position (line and column number).

Second, you build a map in the editor: abstractly, for each pixel, the line and column number of the source file being displayed.  (In practice, if your displayed lines are fixed height, and your displayed characters are fixed with, you can get by with a map from the displayed-line-number to the source line number).

Now mapping back and forth from screen position (e.g., cursor location) to AST node is easy, even if you edit the tree and/or change what part is displayed.

Some complications occur when you insert new tree nodes in the tree because they don't have a "file position".  That's OK, you can assign them arbitrary line/column numbers that don't overlap with any existing line numbers.  When you write out the modified tree to file, you don't really need the line/column numbers anymore, so you can ignore them all.

Comment: How do I stamp each AST node with a source file position though after the AST has been created?

Comment: You probably can't.  Why can't you stamp the nodes as they are created?

Comment: I was thinking of using a parser as it is, but it looks like I do need to modify it.